# How to attach elastic beanstalk with shared load balancer's target group in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I've created an Elastic Beanstalk environment resource and shared an Application load balancer resource using Terraform. The elastic beanstalk's environment resource is assigned to the application load balancer's ID using the Eb namespace settings.

The problem is the target group generated by elastic beanstalk is not set to the default listener rule. This is making the load balancer's URL show a 502 error when opened. It will run fine if I manage the default listener rule in the load balancer to forward the traffic to the Eb Target group.

So I'm searching for a way to assign the target group in **Elastic Beanstalk** to use the one created by the load balancer or let the load balancer's listener resource forward to the **Elastic Beanstalk's** target group by default. Using terraform.

Is there a way to do that? I searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution.

I tried to attach the load balance's listener with **Elastic Beanstalk's** target group or attach **Elastic Beanstalk** with the load balancer's target group using Terraform.

I expect the shared load balancer's listener to forward traffic to the elastic beanstalk's target group by default using the terraform template

Answer (score 0):

In the terraform config where you create the shared load balancer, did you create a port 80 listener for it? In order for beanstalk to create the rule (which should forward to its target group), the listener needs to already exist.

If you're not happy with the rule beanstalk creates, you can explicitly make your own by finding the target group beanstalk made with something like this:

```
data "aws_lb_target_group" "my_target_group" {
  tags = {
    "elasticbeanstalk:environment-name" = "THE_ENVIRONMENT_NAME"
  }

  depends_on = [THE_ENVIRONMENT_RESOURCE]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "http_rule" {
  listener_arn = SHARED_ALB_PORT_80_LISTENER_ARN

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = data.aws_lb_target_group.my_target_group.arn
  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["YOUR_URL.COM"]
    }
  }
}
```

(replacing stuff in CAPS)